# refreshControl onRefresh not fired

Tags: react-native

The `refreshing` and other props are working.

Only the `onRefresh` is not fired when I pull down the list view. The loading icon is showing but the callback function didn't work.

- React native: 0.50 and 0.51
- iOS 10.3.1

[image: inline]

```
  _onRefresh(){
        this.setState({refreshing: true});
        console.log('yoyo')
    }

    wordListView() {
        return (
            <View>
                <View style={{marginBottom: 100}}>
                    <SwipeListView
                        // autoHideHeader={true}
                        // renderHeader={this.renderHeader}
                        refreshControl={
                            <RefreshControl
                                refreshing={false}
                                onRefresh={this._onRefresh.bind(this)}
                                progressBackgroundColor="#ffff00" />
                        }
                        initialListSize={1}
                        ....
                    />
                </View>
            </View>
        )
    }
```

Comment: On first glance more information is needed about the SwipeListView component. It looks like you are using `react-native-swipe-list-view`.
Is this the case?